# Lightning Network: can I create a channel from a preexisting channel?

Tags: bitcoin-core, lightning-network

If I open a channel with myself for 0.01 BTC, with one end having all, and the other having none, could I create an updated contract, or state, to send 0.001 BTC to an address owned by Alice, even though this address would not be in the blockchain, whereby she now has a valid channel with 0.001 BTC, and I have 0.009?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot. This is because you could always revert the state of the channel to the one where you held all of the coins without Alice being able to have any recourse if you do so.

Comment: I actually knew this much before asking. It is just that I have a use case for this, so I wanted to make sure that I wasn’t missing a way to make such a thing possible. Essentially I wanted to be able to give away small amounts without having to open so many channels, also reducing block space usage.